# How to debug failed import for Python dragnet module?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I'm trying to use a python module called dragnet:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dragnet

I am inexperienced in the python ecosystem. I am following the setup example on that page. Which looks like it should be straightforward. My current code is:

```
import requests
from dragnet import content_extractor

# fetch HTML
url = 'https://moz.com/devblog/dragnet-content-extraction-from-diverse-feature-sets/'
r = requests.get(url)

# get main article without comments
content = content_extractor.analyze(r.content)
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Kevs-MBP:bin kev$ python dragnet.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dragnet.py", line 2, in <module>
    from dragnet import content_extractor
  File "/Users/kev/code/easeread/bin/dragnet.py", line 2, in <module>
    from dragnet import content_extractor
ImportError: cannot import name content_extractor
```

I am on OSX.

```
Kevs-MBP:bin kev$ python --version
Python 2.7.13
```

Comment: how did you install  dragnet.

Comment: by following the "installing" steps at the page i linked to: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dragnet#installing  `pip install dragnet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok apparently python doesn't like the entry point sharing the same name as the module you're importing so renaming dragnet.py solved it

Answer (score 2):

This means that the dragnet module is installed on your computer since it says the message

```
ImportError: cannot import name content_extractor
```

You can get the list of available modules for dragnet using the below command. I am using a debian machine. The module exists if you can see my dir object.

Go to terminal and get inside the python interpreter.

```
varad@adithya-pc ~ $ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dragnet
>>> dir(dragnet)                                                                                                                                                        
['AllFeatures', 'Blockifier', 'BlockifyError', 'CSSFeatures', 'ContentExtractionModel', 'NormalizedFeature', 'PartialBlock', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__n
ame__', '__package__', '__path__', '_weninger', 'blocks', 'compat', 'content_comments_extractor', 'content_extraction_model', 'content_extractor', 'evaluation_metrics',
 'features', 'kmeans', 'kohlschuetter', 'kohlschuetter_features', 'models', 'readability', 'readability_features', 'util', 'weninger', 'weninger_features_kmeans']      
>>>
```

Steps followed in debian machine for installation

```
 sudo pip install numpy
 sudo pip install cython
 sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev
 sudo pip install dragnet
```